# some generic questions about neo4j

Tags: servlets, nosql, neo4j, neo4jphp

I'm new to non-php web applications and to nosql databases. I was looking for a smart solution matching my application requirements and I was very surprised when I knew that there exist graph based db. Well I found neo4j very nice and very suitable for my application, but as I've already wrote I'm new to this and I have some limitations in understending how it works. I hope you guys could help me to learn.

1. If I embed neo4j in a servlet program then the database access I create is shared among the different threads of that servet right? so I need to put database creation in init() method and the shutdown in the destroy() right? And it will be thread safe.(every dot is a "right?") But what if I want to create a database shared among the whole application?
2. I heard that graph databases in general relies on a relational low level. Is that true for neo4j? But if it is then I see an high level interface to the real persistence layer, so what a Connection is in this case? Are there some techniques like connection pooling or these low level things are all managed by neo4j?
3. In my application I need to join some objects to users and many other classification stuff. any of these object has an unique id (a String). then If some one asks to view some stuff about object having id=QW then I need to load the vertex associate to object.QW. Is this an easy operation for graph datbases?
4. If I need to manage authentications, so as I receive the couple (usr,pwd) and I need to check whether exists this couple in my graph. Is the same problem as before or there exist some good variation for managing authentications?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. If you're coming from PHP world in most cases you're better of running Neo4j in server mode and access it either via REST directly or use a client driver like https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp. If you still want to embed Neo4j in a servlet environment, the GraphDatabaseService is a shared component, maybe stored within the ServletContext. On a per request (and therefore per-thread) basis you start and commit transactions.
2. Neo4j is a native graph database. The bare metal persistence layer is optimized for navigating from one node to its neighbors as fast as possible and written by the Neo4j devteam themselves. There are other graph databases out there reusing other persistence technologies for their underlying persistence.
3. Best thing is to run the Neo4j online course at http://www.neo4j.org/learn/online_course.
4. see [SecurityRules](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/security-server.html#_server_authorization_rules)

Comment: thanks for replying.
So I don't need to set up any connection pooling in order to speed up the multi-user access right?

Comment: No you don't it's just http connections which are pooled anyway afaik. You could only check if Neo4jPHP uses keep-alive internally.

Comment: Ok, I'm using Java in a tomcat environment and I'd prefer to embed neo4j instead of use REST. In this scenario I dont need to pool right?

Comment: In embedded you just have the graphdatabaseservice as global component and then on a per thread basis a transaction. With that in place you can use the API of GraphDatabaseService, Node, Relationship, TraversalDescription, .... in a safe way.

Answer (score 0):

As the Neo4j is NoSql Graph Database,
Genration of the Unique ID you have to handle using the GUID(with 3.x autonincremented proery also supported for particular label),
as the Neo4j default genrated id is unique but can be realocated to the another object once the first assigned object is deleted,
I am .net developer in my project I used the Neo4j rest api it works well, i will sugesst you to go with that,as it is implemented using async-awit programing pattern, so long running operation you can pass to DB and utilize your web server resources in more prominent way.